# Running Python Line by Line in SSH Terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run PySpark code line by line in Visual Studio Code over an SSH Terminal to a cluster. Pressing Shift+Enter opens up a traditional local Python terminal. I have tried setting key bindings to run selected lines in active terminal, however this only works if I run code one line at a time because the terminal does not know to wait for a return before sending the next highlighted line, producing an error. How can I send multiple lines of code to an ssh terminal? Any ideas?

Comment: isn't the entire point of using a terminal to send one line at a time?

Comment: At least for my situation development requires running code in blocks. Its difficult to do that when you have to run 80 lines of code individually.

Comment: then why do you not white a program?

Comment: you can just make a regular text document, write the code, save it as 'thing.py' (remember to not save it as a .txt) and then you have an executable program. Of course you could also use an IDE

Comment: Are you making the SSH connection via the terminal yourself or are you using VS Code's new [remote development](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/05/02/remote-development) support?